# How can I type left (sub)superscript?

Tags: notebooks, formatting

I want to type in my variable next to its plot and I'm typing the text in using `Inset`. However my variable has superscripts to the left. Say it looks like this:

$ \sideset{_a^b}{'}F $

How can I type this in *Mathematica*?

Right now I just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> and fill in the super/subscript and then delete the place holder for the regular script. This works for a while but if I correct something else on the plot then it automatically vanishes. Is there a stable and standard way to do this?

Comment: You can use Palettes -> Basic Math Assistant.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Thanks, that's a good idea. For some reason I prefer to write a code rather than use the Palatte so I forget about it most of the times.

Comment: Usually if you hover your mouse over the palette you'll see the required alias/key combo to type as well.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries oh cool. Thx!

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries So There is a command in the Palette for left superscript but for whatever reasons when I hover my mouse over it the tooltip doesn't show. The tooptip is working for everything else. Hopefully it will show at a later time. thx.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rather using manual typesetting tricks, I suggest you define **template boxes** for these three notations. Add the three styles below to your document's style definitions. (In case you're not familiar with the style editor, to do this: <kbd>Format</kbd> > <kbd>Edit Stylesheet...</kbd>; and for each of the 3 styles, start typing to create a new cell, press Ctrl-Shift-E to edit the code, and replace with each cell code shown below, and press Ctrl-Shift-E.)

`LeftSuperscript` style:

```
Cell[StyleData["LeftSuperscript"],
 TemplateBoxOptions->{
  DisplayFunction->(RowBox[{
   SuperscriptBox[" ", #2],
   "\[NegativeVeryThinSpace]",
   #1
  }]&),
  Tooltip->Automatic}]
```

`LeftSubscript` style:

```
Cell[StyleData["LeftSubscript"],
 TemplateBoxOptions->{
  DisplayFunction->(RowBox[{
   SubscriptBox["\[InvisibleSpace]", #2],
   "\[NegativeVeryThinSpace]",
   #1
  }]&),
  Tooltip->Automatic}]
```

`LeftSubsuperscript` style:

```
Cell[StyleData["LeftSubsuperscript"],
 TemplateBoxOptions->{
  DisplayFunction->(RowBox[{
   SubsuperscriptBox["\[InvisibleSpace]", #2, #3],
   "\[NegativeVeryThinSpace]",
   #1
  }]&),
  Tooltip->Automatic}]
```

## Input

The boxes themselves are written using box expressions like `TemplateBox[{"x","y"}, "LeftSuperscript"]`.

For convenient editing, also create input aliases, by adding another cell to the stylesheet:

```
Cell[StyleData[All],
  InputAliases->{
    "l^"->TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]","\[Placeholder]"},
    "LeftSuperscript"],
    "l_"->TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]","\[Placeholder]"},
    "LeftSubscript"],
    "l_^"->TemplateBox[{"\[SelectionPlaceholder]","\[Placeholder]","\[Placeholder]"},
    "LeftSuperscript"]
}]
```

Then, you can create left superscripts (<kbd>Esc</kbd> `l` `^` <kbd>Esc</kbd>), subscripts (<kbd>Esc</kbd> `l` `_` <kbd>Esc</kbd>), and subsuperscripts (<kbd>Esc</kbd> `l` `_` `^` <kbd>Esc</kbd>) while editing using the respective input shortcuts.

## Output

To get Mathematica to display the typeset forms in the output, execute

```
LeftSuperscript /: MakeBoxes[LeftSuperscript[braw_, supraw_], form_] :=
  With[{
      b = MakeBoxes[braw, form],
      sup = MakeBoxes[supraw, form]
    },
    TemplateBox[{b, sup}, "LeftSuperscript"]
  ];
LeftSubscript /: MakeBoxes[LeftSubscript[braw_, subraw_], form_] := 
  With[{
      b = MakeBoxes[braw, form],
      sub = MakeBoxes[subraw, form]
    },
    TemplateBox[{b, sub}, "LeftSubscript"]
  ];
LeftSubsuperscript /: 
  MakeBoxes[LeftSubsuperscript[braw_, subraw_, supraw_], form_] := 
  With[{
      b = MakeBoxes[braw, form],
      sub = MakeBoxes[subraw, form],
      sup = MakeBoxes[supraw, form]
    },
    TemplateBox[{b, sub, sup}, "LeftSubsuperscript"]
  ];
```

## Result

It looks reasonable in both code and typeset-math forms, except for the `LeftSubsuperscript` when the subscript and superscript differ greatly in length:

[image: left boxes in use]

## Discussion

Template boxes are harder to mess up while editing than manual typesetting.

Another advantage of using [semantically-correct typesetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_markup) is that the boxes can be parsed and manipulated as expressions. For example, if you want to use $^y x$ to denote [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)—

```
Tetration[a_, n_Integer] := 
    If[n == 0, 1, a^Tetration[a, n - 1]] /; a > 0 \[And] n >= 0;
```

— you could define

```
LeftSuperscript = Tetration;
```

and use it:

[image: typing]

resulting in:
[image: result]

You could also symbolically manipulate or generate expressions containing your notation.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I learnt the most from your answer. thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I don't know how you would type this in directly, but the following may get you a step closer.

How about leaving a placeholder?

```
Row[{Style[Subsuperscript[Invisible["x"], "a", "d"], Italic], 
     Style[Superscript["F", "'"], Italic]}]//TraditionalForm
```

[image: traditional script]

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you. I'll wait a couple of days to see what other suggestions come up before I accept. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's  a nice one

Answer (score 7):

There is quite a bit of "micro" tweeking available for typesetting these positions. Starting with Davids answer:

```
Row[{
   Style[Subsuperscript[Invisible["x"], "a", "b"], Italic], 
   Style[Superscript["F", "\[Prime]"], Italic]}] // TraditionalForm
```

you can use `"\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]"` instead of `Invisible["x"]` as per @kgulers answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/overlay-alignment). The advantage in doing so is that you do not have unwanted space to the left of your typeset expression. Then adjust the vertical positions of your sub and superscripts:

```
Row[{
   Style[Subsuperscript["\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]", "a", "b"], Italic, 
    ScriptBaselineShifts -> {0.65, 0.75}], 
   Style[Superscript["F", "\[Prime]"], Italic, 
    ScriptBaselineShifts -> {Automatic, 0.85}]}] // TraditionalForm
```

And you can also nudge subscripts and superscripts in inline cells around via the **Insert>Typesetting** menu or programmatically with `AdjustmentBox`. Here I am moving `a` and `b` to the right, closer to `F`.

```
Row[{
    Style[
     Subsuperscript["\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]", 
      AdjustmentBox["a", BoxMargins -> {{0.17, -0.17}, {0., 0.}}], 
      AdjustmentBox["b", BoxMargins -> {{0.17, -0.17}, {0., 0.}}]], 
     Italic, ScriptBaselineShifts -> {0.65, 0.75}], 
    Style[Superscript["F", "\[Prime]"], Italic, 
     ScriptBaselineShifts -> {Automatic, 0.85}]}] // 
  DisplayForm // TraditionalForm
```

Finally you can control the size of the subscripts and superscripts with `ScriptSizeMultipliers`

```
Style[
   Row[{
     Style[
      Subsuperscript["\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]", 
       AdjustmentBox["a", BoxMargins -> {{0.17, -0.17}, {0.5, 0.}}], 
       AdjustmentBox["b", BoxMargins -> {{0.17, -0.17}, {0., 0.}}]], 
      Italic, ScriptBaselineShifts -> {0.5, 0.75}], 
     Style[Superscript["F", "\[Prime]"], Italic, 
      ScriptBaselineShifts -> {Automatic, 0.85}]}], 
   ScriptSizeMultipliers -> {0.6}, ScriptMinSize -> 6] // 
  DisplayForm // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the typesetting tips. This really helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> after adding these entries in `KeyEventTranslations.tr`:

```
Item[KeyEvent["6", Modifiers -> {Control, Command}], FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], All, Word], FrontEnd`NotebookApply[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]", "\[Placeholder]"], "\[SelectionPlaceholder]"}]]}]],
Item[KeyEvent["-", Modifiers -> {Control, Command}], FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], All, Word], FrontEnd`NotebookApply[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], RowBox[{SubscriptBox["\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]", "\[Placeholder]"], "\[SelectionPlaceholder]"}]]}]],
```