# Overlay alignment

Tags: alignment

Borrowing `triangularArrayLayout` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/visualize-pascals-triangle-and-other-triangle-shaped-lists), I have:

```
triangularArrayLayout[triArray_List, opts___] := 
 Module[{n = Length[triArray]}, 
  Graphics[MapIndexed[
    Text[Style[#1, 
       Large], {Sqrt[3] (n - 1 + #2.{-1, 2}), 3 (n - First[#2] + 1)}/
       2] &, triArray, {2}], opts]]

n = 6;
s = 500;
coeffs = triangularArrayLayout[Table[Row[{"C(", i, ",", j, ")"}], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, i}], 
   ImageSize -> s];
tri = triangularArrayLayout[Table[Binomial[i, j], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, i}], 
   ImageSize -> s];
layers = {Overlay[{coeffs, Show[tri, TextStyle -> GrayLevel[.8]]}, Alignment -> Top], 
   Overlay[{tri, Show[coeffs, TextStyle -> GrayLevel[.8]]}, Alignment -> Top]};

Manipulate[layers[[u]], {{u, 1, " "}, {1 -> "binomial coefficients", 
   2 -> "Pascal's triangle"}}, ControlType -> RadioButtonBar]
```

but the vertical alignment is off:

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is the main issue, but I am also curious how to:

1. typeset the $C(n,r)$ as `TraditionalForm` (with the varying $n$ and $r$ values throughout)
2. typeset the $C(n,r)$ as $_{n}C_{r}$ (also with the varying $n$ and $r$ values).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Using the same option  `ImagePadding->k` in both `coeff` and `tri` fixes the vertical alignment problem.
- `C` is a protected symbol (it is used for representing constants generated in  symbolic computations.) Instead you can use `\[ScriptCapitalC]`:

Then

```
TraditionalForm[\[ScriptCapitalC][n,r]]
```

gives

[image]

and

```
 TraditionalForm[\[ScriptCapitalC][9,3]]
```

gives

[image]

- For typsetting `C(n,r)` as $_{n}C_{r}$

you can use

```
nCr /: MakeBoxes[nCr[n_, r_], StandardForm] :=
   RowBox[{SubscriptBox["\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]",  MakeBoxes[n, StandardForm]], 
     SubscriptBox["C", MakeBoxes[r, StandardForm]]}]
```

With

```
 nCr[3, 2]
```

you get

[image]

and

```
TraditionalForm[nCr[3, 2]]
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Version 7 does not have Overlay, but one can produce a similar effect from within `Graphics`.  Using your code with this substitution:

```
layers = {Graphics[{coeffs[[1]], Opacity[0.3], tri[[1]]}], 
          Graphics[{tri[[1]], Opacity[0.3], coeffs[[1]]}]};
```

yields:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, this is also helpful to me.