# What are \[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase] and \[InvisiblePostfixScriptBase]?

Tags: front-end, undocumented, documentation, named-characters

In [the non-printing characters documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/NonPrintingCharacters.html), I see two named characters that are largely undocumented: [`\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/character/InvisiblePrefixScriptBase.html) and [`\[InvisiblePostfixScriptBase]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/character/InvisiblePostfixScriptBase.html).

Interestingly, they have input aliases defined: `[Esc]i-[Esc]` and `[Esc]-i[Esc]`.

What are they used for?

Comment: Related (possible dupe): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1/5 I'd say that they're mostly for typesetting purposes and for finer control of the placements and positioning of subscripts/superscripts. You might probably use one of these when you need a subscript/superscript that's not attached to any symbol.

Comment: Two examples of the first one are (1) `TraditionalForm[Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, d]]`, and (2) [this Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15669/125)  where it is used to typset $_{n}C_{r}$

Comment: @kguler: So it seems like the Prefix one is meant as an invisible base character for sub-/superscripts that are typeset before the conceptual base character. But the Postfix one is still a mystery.

Comment: I have not come across any usage examples of `\[InvisiblePostfixScriptBase]` -- who knows? Maybe for right-to-left scripts it works similar to the Prefix one?

Comment: I use `\[InvisiblePostfixScriptBase]` to emulate the spaces and alignments in some tensor notions. In LaTeX it's usually done by `\phantom` command. Compare `RowBox[{SubscriptBox["F","a"],SubsuperscriptBox["\[InvisiblePostfixScriptBase]","b","c"]}]//DisplayForm` to LaTeX code `F_{ab}^{\phantom{a}c}`.

Comment: @Silvia I feel like this comment is quite accurate answer, please consider posting it :)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks :) Will do it when I am on a computer.

Comment: @Silvia ok :- )

Answer (score 2):

As the comments to OP described, those invisible marks are usually used as placeholders / anchors for typesetting.

For example, we can use `\[InvisiblePostfixScriptBase]` to emulate the spaces and alignments in some tensor notations. In LaTeX it's usually done by the `\phantom` command: Compare `RowBox[{SubscriptBox["F", "a"],SubsuperscriptBox["\[InvisiblePostfixScriptBase]"‌, "b", "c"]}] // DisplayForm` to LaTeX code `F_{ab}^{ \phantom{a} c }`.