# Symbol with left and right subscript and right superscript

Tags: custom-notation

I am trying to come up with a variable that has a left and right subscript and right superscript. I have tried the following

```
Notation`Symbolize[
 Notation`ParsedBoxWrapper[{SubscriptBox["RVC", "B"], 
   SubsuperscriptBox["RV", "BV", "KJK"]}]]
```

which gives a variable that has a right superscript that in turn has a right superscript and subscript but isn't what I'm looking for

Other things I have tried is the following

```
nCr /: MakeBoxes[nCr[n_, r_], StandardForm] := 
 RowBox[{SubscriptBox["\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]", 
    MakeBoxes[n, StandardForm]], 
   SubscriptBox["C", MakeBoxes[r, StandardForm]]}]
```

which gives a variable with a left and right superscript but won't translate to a variable with `Symbolize`.

Comment: `nCr` from [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15670/125).

Comment: It appears `Symbolize` will not accept row boxes. However for typesetting you can adapt the nCr approach to render what you want

Comment: I can create (sort of, it needs some adjustment) the form I want with the following:

Comment: MakeBoxes[MyHead2[a_, b_, c_, d_], 
  form : (StandardForm | TraditionalForm) : StandardForm] := 
 Module[{dispFunc}, 
  dispFunc = 
   GridBox[{{"", "", #1}, {"", #2, ""}, {#3, "", #4}}, 
     GridBoxDividers -> {"Rows" -> {{False}}, 
       "Columns" -> {{False}}}] &;
  TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[a, form], MakeBoxes[b, form], 
    MakeBoxes[c, form], MakeBoxes[d, form]}, "String", 
   DisplayFunction -> dispFunc, 
   InterpretationFunction -> (GridBox[{{#1, "", ""}, {"", #2, 
         ""}, {#3, "", #4}}, 
       GridBoxDividers -> {"Rows" -> {{False}}, 
         "Columns" -> {{False}}}] &)]]

Comment: with the following at the beginning of the previous code:
Clear[MyHead2];
MyHead2 /:
if I use the Ctrl+Shift+E to get the underlying code then try and turn the mixed variables into a single variable with Notation`Symbolize[Notation`ParsedBoxWrapper[]] like I do with the first example I gave, all I get are errors. The commands are the same type (ones that come from the pallet) but I can't get the single variable that it is supposed to provide. Are there other ways to do this that don't require the use of the Notation Package? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here is the answer:

Comment: Here is the answer:
1) Using Symbolize from palette AND Completely Overwriting Yellow Box (i.e. don't just click and paste in cursor, highlight entire yellow box)
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[TagBox[RowBox[{SubscriptBox["","RRR"],SubsuperscriptBox["BRV","BV","KJK"]}], "genericRRRTag", Editable->False, Selectable->False]]]
2) Get Name:
Names["\*RRR\*"]
3) Get Display form:
pasteINname //DisplayForm
4) get AddInputAlias from palette then paste into the cursor (i.e. don't overwrite yellow box) the results from DisplayForm

This creates the alias