# How to set a TraditionalForm output for a symbol

Tags: function-construction, formatting, symbols, traditional-form

How do I set a `TraditionalForm` output for a particular symbol/function?

In particular I would like my user-defined symbol `pvB[n,P,x,s,m0,m1]` to have an output that looks like $B_{0\ldots0 1\ldots1}(s,m0,m1)$.  Here, the number of $0$'s in the subscript is $n$ and the number of $1$'s in the subscript is $P-n$.  The third parameter shouldn't appear in the output, and $s$, $m0$, $m1$ are just arguments.  (Of course, if this appears as part of a larger expression, I need to have it be formatted appropriately).

So for example:

```
TraditionalForm[pvB[2,4,x,s,m0,m1]]
```

should give

$B_{0011}(s,m0,m1)$.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In addition to the answers below this technique and discussion be useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15058/how-can-i-type-left-subsuperscript/15131#15131

Comment: QuantumDot, any comments on my answer?  It seems like the simplest way to proceed to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the formatting command that does this:

```
pvB /: MakeBoxes[pvB[n1_, n2_, x_, s_, m0_, m1_], TraditionalForm] :=

  RowBox[{SubscriptBox["B", 
    RowBox[{Sequence @@ Riffle[Table["0", {n1}], "\[ThinSpace]"], 
      "\[ThinSpace]", 
      Sequence @@ Riffle[Table["1", {n2 - n1}], "\[ThinSpace]"]}]], "(",
    Sequence @@ Riffle[Map[ToBoxes, {x, s, m0, m1}], ","], ")"}]
```

For example:

```
pvB[2, 4, x, s, m0, m1] // TraditionalForm
```

> $B_{0\,0\,1\,1}(s,m0,m1)$

The `\[ThinSpace]` will display as a small empty string, but is useful to insure that the indices are separated by just a tiny bit.

**Edit: why use MakeBoxes?**

I prefer to use `MakeBoxes` to define output formats, even though there is the function `Format` too. The reason my default choice is `MakeBoxes` is described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4119830/915703). Essentially, this becomes important if you want to be able to re-use your formatted output as input in later computations.

Answer (score 5):

I might be oversimplifying something but I believe you can use:

```
MakeBoxes[pvB[n_, P_, _, x__], fmt : TraditionalForm] :=
  MakeBoxes[#, fmt] & @ Subscript[Defer @ B, Row[1 ~Table~ {n} ~PadLeft~ P]][x]

pvB[2, 4, x, s, m0, m1] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `PadLeft` is a nice touch.

Comment: This is certainly a very short piece of code, but I've never seen many of the symbols/functions in here.  I'd have to investigate!

Comment: @QuantumDot I'd be happy to try to explain any part of it.  It's really fairly simple, though that doesn't mean easy to read.  Possibly my use of ~infix~ confuses you but I prefer it to stacked brackets.  Basically I create the list of zeros and ones with `1 ~Table~ {n} ~PadLeft~ P` then put it in a Subscript with `B` (held with `Defer` in case `B` has a value).  This Subscript acts as a function and gets any remaining arguments, and finally it is passed back to `MakeBoxes` for automatic formatting.  I find this much cleaner than fully crafting the Box form manually as Jens did.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternate way to format it using `Format`:

```
Format[pvB[n_, P_, x_, s_, m0_, m1_], TraditionalForm] := DisplayForm@RowBox[{
    SubscriptBox["B", StringJoin@SparseArray[{i_ :> "1" /; i > P - n}, P, "0"]],
    RowBox[{ "(", Sequence @@ Riffle[ToBoxes /@ {s, m0, m1}, ","], ")" }]
}]
```

[image]

This definition will be saved in the `FormatValues` for `pvB`.

Comment: This answer is very economical, but the problem is that if the `pvB` function appears in a larger expression, an unneeded pair of parenthesis is added around it.  Try `TraditionalForm[3 pvB[2,4,x,s,m0,m1]]`, for example.  How should I remove it?

Comment: @QuantumDot I'm not near mma to test it right now, but I believe the reason is because `Format` is mainly for display purposes only and not for use in computations, so I would recommend his approach for flexibility (see the last paragraph in Jens' answer). Mine isn't any more "economical" than Jens'... if you're referring to the compactness of generating the "0011" string, then you can very well use what I have above with `MakeBoxes` as in Jens' answer.

Comment: Oh, I am just saying that the result of the example in my comment above is:  $3\big(B_{0011}(s,m0,m1)\big)$, and the outer parenthesis is extraneous.

Comment: @QuantumDot Yeah, I understood that and I'm saying that I think it's because of the reason in Michael Pilat's answer (but I'm not sure)

Comment: Yes, you are right; Jens' answer doesn't lead to extraneous parentheses.  And, yeah -- I thought your answer was more economical because it took 'fewer lines.'  Those are my newbie instincts showing up.