# How to format symbols with tooltip in TraditionalForm?

Tags: output-formatting, tooltip, traditional-form

This is a follow up to [this previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17633/how-to-set-a-traditionalform-output-for-a-symbol), where a `TraditionalForm` formatting was defined for the symbol `pvB`, so that `TraditionalForm[pvB[2,4,x,s,m0,m1]]` would give $B_{0011}(s,m0,m1)$.

I now want to mimic the behavior of TraditionalForm formatting of built-in special functions, where hovering the cursor over it would display a tooltip with the name of the built-in symbol.

Below is such an example.  Hovering the mouse over the TraditionalForm version of the `BesselJ` function displays the tooltip:

[image]

How do I modify the code of the answers given to [this previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17633/how-to-set-a-traditionalform-output-for-a-symbol) so that hovering over $B_{0011}(s,m0,m1)$ would give a tooltip message "`PVB`"?

Comment: Thank you for adding the corresponding method for a pre-formed box, and for the accept!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be as simple as wrapping any one of the answers to your previous question within `Tooltip`. In this case, I prefer to start from [Mr. Wizard's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17677/27951), because it allows me to stay away from explicitly building up the necessary `Box` expression.

```
MakeBoxes[pvB[n_Integer, P_Integer, _, x__], fmt : TraditionalForm] :=
 MakeBoxes[#, fmt] &@
  Tooltip[
    Subscript[
      Defer[B],
      Row[PadLeft[Table[1, {n}], P]]
    ][x], "pvB"
  ]

pvB[3, 5, x, s, m0, m1] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

---

**edit by QuantumDot**

And if you already have a `Box` expression, then wrap with `TooltipBox`.  For example, using [Jens' answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17635/27951),

```
pvB /: MakeBoxes[pvB[n1_Integer, n2_Integer, x_, s_, m0_, m1_], TraditionalForm] := 
TooltipBox[
  RowBox[{SubscriptBox["B", 
    RowBox[{Sequence @@ Riffle[Table["0", {n1}], "\[ThinSpace]"], 
     "\[ThinSpace]", 
     Sequence @@ Riffle[Table["1", {n2 - n1}], "\[ThinSpace]"]}]], 
     "(", Sequence @@ Riffle[Map[ToBoxes, {x, s, m0, m1}], ","], ")"}],
 "pvB"]
```

Comment: Just a caveat for the second approach: anything more complex than a `String` or `List` within the second argument of `TooltipBox` (e.g. `TooltipBox[..., <||>]`) needs to be wrapped into `ToBoxes` otherwise the tooltip won't format correctly. Moreover, the formatter should pre-check argument types, as in symbolic cases no formatting can be done (i.e. `n1` and `n2` must be integers). I have edited this into your answer.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Very good points. Thank you for the edits as well.