# Superscript standalone text

Tags: text

How do I write a superscript text standalone, without implying power? E.g.

> ToExpression[25]<>"CNTRL+^oC"

doesn't format well, italicizing o and leaving whitespace in-between the number and Centigrade symbol.

How do I in general write text which is superscripted?

Comment: For your specific example, you can simply use `\[Degree]C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I write a superscript text standalone, without implying power?

Like this

```
Superscript["", "more text"]
```

[image]

As pointed out by MikeLimaOscar, `Superscript[\[Null], "more text"]` will produce something similar without a string in the main part of the text.

If you need to put text after the subscript rather than before, you can follow the directions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15131/9490) or do something like this

```
Row[{Superscript["", "more text"], "text"}]
```

[image]

Comment: but how to do superscript without the "text" part, so it will output "more text" superscript, without any white spaces before it?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question, I think you can just use a blank string there

Comment: There is also the invisible character, `\[Null]`, that can be used as the base of super/subscripts.

Comment: Thanks, that's even better.  I was trying `Null` but it would actually print `Null`

Comment: Can I put superscript preceding the "text"?

Comment: @AlGuy yes, I believe you then use the `\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]` character. These forms are available in the Typesetting palettes.

Comment: @AlGuy, that isn't what you mentioned in the first post.  Try to describe **exactly** what you are looking for from the get go.  A "standalone superscript" is much different than a superscript on the left.

Answer (score 3):

If it is this specific example you are interested in, you could have found it out yourself by evaluating

```
Quantity[25, "DegreesCelsius"]
```

and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> when the cursor is in the output cell. There, you would have found

```
Cell[BoxData[
 TemplateBox[{"25","\"\[Degree]C\"","degrees Celsius","\"DegreesCelsius\""},
...]
```

which would have given you the hint that xzczd gave you. Therefore, you can use

```
"25\[Degree]C"
```